# How do I groupby a Boolean len count?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

SOLVED
For context, I want to find out which leads to the highest count.

left = false means the worker is still with the company.

I’ve already found out the len count of the number of left = false. But not sure how to group the len count. Thank you :)

Here is what ive attempted but the third line leads to an error

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your request correctly, you need:

```
df[df['left']==False].pivot_table(index='paygrade',
                                  values='uid',
                                  aggfunc='count')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read the dataframe into a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv("dataframe.csv")

# Filter the dataframe to only include employees who are still with the company
df_filtered = df[df['left'] == False]

# Group the dataframe by paygrade and count the number of employees in each paygrade
df_grouped = df_filtered.groupby('paygrade').size()

# Convert the Series to a NumPy array
array = df_grouped.to_numpy()

# Find the index of the highest value in the array
max_index = np.argmax(array)

# Get the paygrade corresponding to the highest value
highest_paygrade = df_grouped.index[max_index]

# Print the highest paygrade
print(highest_paygrade)
```

Output:

Manager

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).